# can I bind event to a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have collection of such classes:

```
public class class1
{
    public double first {get;set;}
    public double second {get;set;}

    public void divide(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        first/=2;
        second/=2;
    }

}

ObservableCollection<class1> collection1;
```

That are displayed using wpf and databinding:

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding first}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding second}" />
            <Button Content="Divide" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My question is: can I somehow bind each button to it's instance's function divide?

Comment: I think you can, but normally I will binding to a common `command` and just pass each `class1` as the `commandparameter`. What exactly do you want to achieve by clicking the `button`?

Comment: As in example above, I'd like to operate on classes displayed by ListBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Commands.

Assume you have a `DelegateCommand` class (that derives from [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
public class class1
{
    public double first {get;set;}
    public double second {get;set;}

    public DelegateCommand DivideCommand{get;set;}

    public class1()
    {
         DivideCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.Divide)
    }

    private void Divide(object parameter)
    {
        first/=2;
        second/=2;
    }
}
```

Then bind the command to the button:

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding first}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding second}" />
            <Button Content="Divide" Command="{Binding DivideCommand}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Implementing a `DelegateCommand` is very simple, [here an example](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with [Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18873424/933416), but you *can* use a common event handler, because the source of the event will be available through the EventArgs. Assuming you're using a code-behind (.xaml.cs), you can define an event handler like this there:

```
private void DivideButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var button = (Button)e.Source;  // <-- the specific button that was clicked
    var c1 = (class1)button.DataContext;  // <-- the instance bound to this button
    c1.Divide();
}
```

In `class1`:

```
public void Divide() {
    first/=2;
    second/=2;
}
```

In XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding first}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding second}" />
        <Button Content="Divide" Click="DivideButton_Click" />
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```